# Linear Independence of $v_1+x, v_2+x, v_3+x$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Let $v_1, v_2, v_3$ be linear independent vectors in vector space V. Suppose $V \neq span\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$ and let $x\notin span\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$ Prove that $v_1+x, v_2+x, v_3+x$ is linearly independent.

My attempt goes like this:

Need to show that $a(v_1+x)+b(v_2+x)+c(v_3+x)=0$ only when $a=b=c=0$.

This statement rearranges to : $a(v_1)+b(v_2)+c(v_3)+(a+b+c)x=0$

Assume $a+b+c=0$ when $a,b,c$ are not all $0$. Then $a=-b-c$. To satisfy the equation above, this would mean that $v_1,v_2,v_3$ is not linearly independent, which is a contradiction.

Therefore one of $a,b,c$ must be zero. WLOG assume  $a=0$ then $b=-c$ where they are not both zero. This would mean that $a(v_1) + (-c)v_2+c(v_3) = 0$, which can not be since it is L.I.

Hence, $a=b=c=0$, showing linear independence.

Is there a flaw with this approach?

Comment: So we have assumed $a+b+c=0$, which gave a contradiction. How do you conclude then that $a=b=c=0$?

Comment: The assuming statement in the contradiction was when "a,b,c" are not all zero. Since that leads to a contradiction they must be all zero.

Comment: No, we assume that $a+b+c=0$ AND $(a,b,c)\neq (0,0,0)$. If this cannot hold, we do not know that $a=b=c=0$. For example, we could have $(a,b,c)=(1,0,0)$, if we haven't $a+b+c=0$ and not all zero.

Comment: Ok, I now updated the proof with assuming one of them is zero. This naturally leads to another contradiction, proving that they are all zero. Is this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're close. It's good to try the $a + b + c = 0$ case, but you haven't talked about what happens in the other case. Also, I think the logic could in this case could be made a little more clear.

When $a + b + c = 0$, then the equation simplifies to
$$av_1 + bv_2 + cv_3 = 0,$$
which implies $a = b = c = 0$ by the linear independence of $v_1, v_2, v_3$. On the other hand, if $a + b + c \neq 0$, then rearranging the equation, we get
$$x = \frac{-a}{a + b + c}v_1 + \frac{-b}{a + b + c}v_2 + \frac{-c}{a + b + c}v_3$$
(note that $a + b + c \neq 0$ is necessary to perform the division), and hence $x \in \operatorname{span}\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$ against assumption. This takes care of the missing case, which turned out not to be possible.